# Api вывод медалей

Tags: json, api, php, mysql

Привет всем. Мне нужно вывести все медали, которые существуют, но у игрока могут быть не иметься не все медали (нету медали `opacity:.4`, есть медаль `opacity:1`).
Но также медали ещё делятся на категории.

У меня имеется список в бд всех медалей с категориями, к примеру:

```
SELECT * FROM `achievements` WHERE category='1'
```

выведет все названия медалей из 1 категории.

И ещё у меня имеется api (json) с медалями игрока, не разбитый по категориям.
[Api](https://api.worldofwarplanes.ru/wowp/account/info/?application_id=demo&fields=achievements&account_id=114462)

В общем, никак не получается у медалей игрока вывести `opacity:1`.

Получилось часть кода сделать. Проблема осталась в том, что не могу вывести медали которых нет у игрока

```
while($rowachiev = mysql_fetch_array($achievements1)){
  foreach($jsonwgapi['data'][$acid['account_id']]['achievements'] as $achiev){
  if($rowachiev['name'] == $achiev['name']){
      echo '<td class="medalopacity" style="opacity:1;"><img id="'.$rowachiev['name'].'" src="'.$rowachiev['image'].'"></td>';  
      echo '<script>';  
      echo 'new Tooltip({
              elem: $(\'#'.$rowachiev['name'].'\'),
      html: "<p style=\'font-weight:bold;\'>'.$rowachiev['name_i18n'].'</p>'.$rowachiev['description'].'"
       });';
      echo '</script>';
  }
```

}
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну так это совсем просто: выбираем все медали, join`им к ним медали игрока и получаем все ачивки вместе с ачивками игрока.

Не знаю структуру ваших таблиц, поэтому приведу схематичный пример:

```
SELECT
    achievements.*,
    player_achievements.achievement_id IS NOT NULL AS has_achievement
FROM achievements

LEFT player_achievements
USING (achievement_id)

WHERE player_achievements.player_id = 1000
```

Таким образом каждая строка кроме самой ачивки будет содержать и поле `has_achievement`, которое будет указывать есть ли данная ачивка у игрока.

**UPD:** Если медали игрока никак из базы не получить (например, периодическим их обновлением через API), то в текущем коде выносим вывод за пределы foreach, в самом foreach в условие добавляем $hasAchievement = true, и при выводе учитываем этот флаг, т.е. грубо будет так:

```
while ($rowachiev = ...) {
    $hasAchievement = false;
    foreach (...) {
        if ($rowachiev['name'] == $achiev['name']) {
            $hasAchievement = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    echo "Медаль: " . var_export($rowachiev, true) . ($hasAchievement ? 'есть' : 'отсутствует'));
}
```

Comment: очивки игрока я получаю с api

Comment: @innot20, а получить их через БД никак не получится? Если совсем никак, то выносим вывод за пределы `foreach`, в самом `foreach` в условие добавляем `$hasAchievement = true`, и при выводе учитываем этот флаг, т.е. грубо будет так:

    while ($rowachiev = ...) {
        $has = false;
        foreach (...) {
            if ($rowachiev['name'] == $achiev['name']) {
                $has = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        echo "Медаль: " . var_export($rowachiev, true) . ($has ? 'есть' : 'отсутствует'));
    }